# Meaning of a novel "division" notation

Tags: notation

In Oliver Salazar Celis' "Adaptive Thiele interpolation," *ACM Communications of Computer Algebra* ***56***(3), Issue 221, September 2022, page 125 (Eq. 1) we find:

[image]

What does this horizontal plus vertical division-like notation mean?

Comment: It's a continued fraction. Wikipedia and other sources attribute the notation to Pringsheim.

Comment: Oh... OK.... thanks.  I'll look it up more thoroughly.   ($+1$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mentioned in the sentence leading up to the formula:

"...*this routine produces a **continued fraction** of the form*..." [[source](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.10957)]


On the notation of continued fractions, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=common%20notations%20for%20continued%20fractions) has

[image]

Comment: Got it... thanks!  ($+1, \checkmark$)